# Proper ARIA usage for pop up windows that are triggered by a button

Tags: html, wai-aria

I'm making the web-UI for my software more accessible by improving the usage of ARIA. In various places, I have multiple pop-up windows that get opened by a button. See the image below for an example. This window is shown when the 'Delete' button is pressed and is closed using the cross in the top right or the 'Cancel' button.

How do I make it clear to ARIA that a specific button shows a window-blocking section? It looks like the [dialog role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/dialog_role) is appropriate? It seems to me like I should supply the ID of the window to the button so that ARIA knows which section is shown when I click the button. But I can't find any descriptor for that. How does ARIA know which element is the window, to which the focus should be given?

[image: Pop up window covering whole page]

---

EDIT:
And how do I tell ARIA that when you click the cross or 'Cancel' button, that the window closes and focus is put back to the 'main' window?

Comment: `aria-label="close pop-up"` will do the trick. A close button is not a dialog, the role of the button is a button which you should **not** specifically redeclare. You do not need to specifically state that closing a pop-up will return you to the main content. It is indicated by the nature of pop-ups.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have a "Close Window" label on the cross and close button. With the dialog, I meant that the mdn docs suggest that you wrap the entire window in a dialog element, not the close button (because that would indeed be illogical).

Comment: that means to give the pop-up container the attributes `aria-role="dialog"` and `aira-haspopup`. Note, that the `aira-role="dialog"` attribute should only be used if you have an interactive input element within the pop-up (not incl. close buttons). See the [haspopup documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-haspopup)

Comment: All my windows _do_ have interactive input. For example the window in the image that I shared has an input (Delete Folder: yes/no) and the 'Delete' button will delete the entry (which in itself I find to be an interactive input). I saw the `haspopup` attr, but it seems strange to me that you don't supply the ID of the window that pops up when you click the button. How can ARIA know where to lay focus to when the window opens? You'd have to supply the ID somewhere right? That's the reason of this post.